# Custom array Index in Mysql Alias

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to know if it is possible to list the records of a Mysql query into custom arrays
Like when I do

```
SELECT CAT.catgryname,count(JB.knifeid) AS total 
FROM jbs AS JB 
LEFT JOIN krgstrs AS KR ON KR.id = JB.knfid 
LEFT JOIN accnts AS ACC ON ACC.job_id = JB.id 
LEFT JOIN catgor AS CAT ON CAT.id = KR.subctid
WHERE JB.usrid =xxx  
GROUP BY CAT.catgryname
```

it gives me

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [CAT] => Array
                (
                    [categoryname] => Fridge Magnet
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total] => 22
                    [MNTH] => Jan
                )

        )
```

I wanted to have a custom index instead of a 0 for the second array nested inside like

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [CAT] => Array
                (
                    [categoryname] => Fridge Magnet
                )

            [DET] => Array
                (
                    [total] => 22
                    [MNTH] => Jan
                )

        )
```

Note the DET instead of a 0 here.

I tried

```
SELECT CAT.catname,count(cat.id) as DET.total
```

But it throws an error as I think it interprets DET to be a table here.
Thanks All.

Comment: Can you give us the whole query ?

Comment: @OrelEraki it just have some joins and a groupby further.

Comment: It is best we see the whole picture and not part of it, so we can tell you what to fix specifically without inflicting changes to the rest of the code.

Comment: why don't you just read all rows and put them into a custom array? would make more sense as doing it on the db-side

Comment: @steve yes you are right but I was thinking if there was a method to do it using MYSQL only so I can spare the use of PHP to make a desirable array out of it.

Comment: @techie_28 - as far as i know, there's no (elegant) way to do this. i'll write an answer on how to transform it on the php-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do this on DB-Side.
However i don't know how you get the array (using `mysqli` or `mysql` PHP extension). Regardless of that, just do that on the PHP-Side, as pointed out in the comments.

Try using this (`$results` is the array you have as described - with indexes `CAT` and  `0`)

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($results as $result) {
    $newArray[] = array(
        'CAT' => array(
            'categoryname' => $result["CAT"]["categoryname"]
        ),
        'DET' => array(
            'total' => $result[0]["total"],
            'MNTH' => $result[0]["MNTH"]
        )
    );
}
```

And there you go with `$newArray`

Comment: You mean its not possible to do this using MYSQL alone?

Comment: you could get an array with 'categoryname', 'total' and 'MONTH' keys, though. just get with `[mysql|mysqli]_fetch_assoc()` function.